beamer: generate front page with different position of elements
This is my (shortened) document:
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\title{Just Like A Woman}
\author{Matěj Cepl}
\date{June 9th}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{front-page-bg.jpg}}

  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}
  \setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white}

% \setbeamertemplate{author}{default}[1][]{%
%     \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
% }
% 
% \setbeamertemplate{date}{default}[1][]{%
%       \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
% }

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vskip0.25\paperheight\par
    \begin{center}
    \usebeamertemplate{title}
    \end{center}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{flushleft}
    \usebeamertemplate{author}\hfill\usebeamertemplate{date}
    \end{flushleft}
}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\end{document}

I would love it to generate something similar to this page, but I still get only this generated page.pdf
How to manipulate the location of the date and the author name? I tried to neutralize the location of the elements as shown above, but it completely broke the \titlepage.

As you are anyway loading the tikz package, you could use it to freely position the elements on your title page.
Using the little trick from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989 makes it easy to use coordinates relative to the page:
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Just Like A Woman}
\author{Matěj Cepl}
\date{June 9th}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white}

% trick taken from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989
\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \node[text width=3cm] at (0.43,0.38) {\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par};
    \node[text width=3cm] at (0.15,0.15) {\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par};    
    \node[text width=3cm] at (0.7,0.15) {\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\usebeamerfont{date}\insertauthor\par};      
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\end{document}



Thank you! This is awesome! One more \centering to title and it works like charm!

@mcepl You're welcome!
